# How to preg_match all style tags?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

How do I **safe match all** `<style>` blocks in body using preg_match_all()?

Google is not my friend today.

```
$haystack = '<body>
<style>
.class {
  foo: bar;
}
</style>
<p>Hello World</p>
<style>
/* A comment for <p> */
.class > p {
  this: that;
}
</style>
<p>Some HTML</p>
</body>';

preg_match_all('#<style>([^<]+)#is', $haystack, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);

preg_match_all('#<style>(.*)</style>#is', $haystack, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

Did not work, as it matched the < in the style comment.

Comment: Regex is not a very good tool for safely processing HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression quantifiers are greedy by default, meaning they match as much as possible. To match as few characters as possible, change the quantifier to lazy (aka non-greedy) by adding a `?` after `.*` for the following:

```
preg_match_all('#<style>(.*?)</style>#is', $haystack, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

You can read more about greedy and lazy quantifiers here:

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php

It's better to use a HTML parser as your regexp may not match all HTML you encounter. For example, the above regexp will not work for `<style type="text/css">`. You could change the regexp to something like `<style[^><]*>` but it's better to use a HTML parser if you can.